# Changing HTML code to CSS

Tags: html, css

I understand css and have an external file, but I don't know how to move everything from this poll to the css file. The poll is under the div id "poll" so anything I change in css will affect the entire poll instead of specific parts. Can I split the question of the poll and the answers into separate divs or is there a better way to re-write the code?

I know that the poll still works but I like to be organized and the validator is showing many errors because of this.

```
<div id="poll">
<form method="post" action="http://poll.pollcode.com/t78ar8">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">What game site do you visit most?</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" id="t78ar8answer1">
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;<font face="Tahoma" size="2" color="000000"><label for="t78ar8answer1">Ign</label></font>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="5">
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" id="t78ar8answer2">
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;
                <label for="t78ar8answer2">GameSpot</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="5">
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" id="t78ar8answer3">
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;<font face="Tahoma" size="2" color="000000"><label for="t78ar8answer3">GameFAQs</label></font>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="5">
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="4" id="t78ar8answer4">
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;<font face="Tahoma" size="2" color="000000"><label for="t78ar8answer4">GamerZone</label></font>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="5">
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="5" id="t78ar8answer5">
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;<font face="Tahoma" size="2" color="000000"><label for="t78ar8answer5">Mmohut</label></font>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" height="10">
                <center>
                    <input type="submit" value=" Vote ">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="submit" name="view" value=" View ">
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </a>&nbsp;</font>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
```

Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qX3Jp/ for a visual. Also, I know the code's format isnt right. I did that because it was all in one line and harder to read. If any additional information is needed, please ask before rejecting my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wh1t3w0lf21/PWQnp/) showing how i would do it. without a table because I hate tables and think that the only time they should be used is to display data and never for page layout.

also all of the styling has been separated from the markup.

for those too lazy to click the link... here is the code.

HTML:

```
<div id="poll">
    <form method="post" action="http://poll.pollcode.com/t78ar8">

        <h2 id="title">What game site do you visit most?</h2>

        <div id="radio_btns">
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" id="t78ar8answer1">Ign<br />
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" id="t78ar8answer2">GameSpot<br />
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" id="t78ar8answer3">GameFAQs<br />
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="4" id="t78ar8answer4">GamerZone<br />
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="5" id="t78ar8answer5">Mmohut
        </div>
        <div id="submit_btns">
            <input type="submit" value=" Vote ">
            <input type="submit" name="view" value=" View ">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#poll {
    margin: 30px 0px 0px 5px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
#radio_btns {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#radio_btns input {
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
}
#title {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#submit_btns {
     margin: 0px 0px 0px 60px;
}
```

notice that I broke the markup into sections and gave them ID's to make the CSS styling easier.

Comment: Thanks. The format is slightly different, but i'm not worried about it. Also, is /> necessary after <br ?

Comment: it is for strict XHTML which is just a habit for me. but just <br> works fine too.

Comment: I'm using strict but i'm still very new to coding so I don't know a lot the specific rules. I got it all to work great. Again, thank you very much. This was really annoying me. lol

Comment: How come you can't friend or message people on here? The inability to communicate with other people makes it a pain.

Comment: your not the first person to think so... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice

Answer (score 1):

I went full form and removed what I see as unnecessary elements: tables + more. I put the font information in the body tag. Everything else in the CSS is layout related.

CSS:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000;
}
label {
    display:block;
}
fieldset {
    border:none;
    text-align:center;
}
legend {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="http://poll.pollcode.com/t78ar8" id="poll">
        <legend>What game site do you visit most?</legend>
        <label for="t78ar8answer1"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" id="t78ar8answer1"> Ign</label>
        <label for="t78ar8answer2"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" id="t78ar8answer2"> GameSpot</label>
        <label for="t78ar8answer3"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" id="t78ar8answer3"> GameFAQs</label>
        <label for="t78ar8answer4"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="4" id="t78ar8answer4"> GamerZone</label>
        <label for="t78ar8answer5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="5" id="t78ar8answer5"> Mmohut</label>
        <fieldset>
          <input type="submit" value=" Vote ">
          <input type="submit" name="view" value=" View ">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: nice use of the legend and fieldset tags! looks like we had basically the same idea.